# Conseguir background/fondo de una imagen dinámicamente

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Estoy empezando a trabajar con los `ImageView` y me gustaría saber como intercambiar los fondos entre ellas dinámicamete.
Supongamos que tengo dos `ImageView`:

1) `ImageView puesto_1_foto_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.puesto_1_foto_1);`

2) `ImageView mi_puesto_foto_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mipuesto_foto_1);`

Lo que querría hacer, es una vez precargadas a través de `java`, acceder a la propia imagen que dichos `ImageView` tienen definidos como `background`, para así ponerle el de uno a la otra, y el de la otra a este primero.

Intentaré explicarlo con una imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Mario, he agregado una respuesta, espero te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Como conseguir la imagen de background/fondo de un `ImageView` dinámicamente.

> Existe alguna forma de conseguir el nombre del background de cada
>   TextView. Por ejemplo, si el primero tiene un background llamado a
>   través de un drawable llamado "fondo1", ¿existe alguna forma de
>   acceder a ese nombre?

Lo que realizarías es acceder a el id de la imagen cargada definiendo el nombre en el tag:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/puesto_1_foto_1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:background="@drawable/fondo1"
    android:tag="fondo1"/>
```

Al obtener la referencia del `ImageView`

```
ImageView puesto_1_foto_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.puesto_1_foto_1);
```

puedes obtener su id mediante su tag:

```
//obtiene el tag del ImageView.
String backgroundImage1 = String.valueOf(imageView1.getTag());
//obtiene id mediante el método getIdentifier().
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(backgroundImage1, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

este id es el que usarias para cargar la imagen en otro `ImageView`:

```
//convierte el id a Drawable
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
//Asigna el Drawable al ImageView.
imageView2.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

---

**Ejemplo:**

De acuerdo al siguiente layout agregamos 2 ImageView a los cuales deseamos intercambiar sus imagenes, para esto en el tag, agregamos el nombre de la imagen ("android" y "robotito" ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android"
        android:tag="android"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/robotito"
        android:tag="robotito"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para intercambiar las imagenes necesitamos obtener el id del recurso cargado en cada ImageView, primeramente obtenemos el nombre del recurso y posteriormente su id, para esto usamos el método [getIdentifier()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
 ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 //Obtiene nombre de imagen mediante el tag.
 String backgroundImage1 = String.valueOf(imageView1.getTag());

 ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
 //Obtiene nombre de imagen mediante el tag.
 String backgroundImage2 = String.valueOf(imageView2.getTag());

  //Obtiene id de imagen cargada en ImageView1
  //backgroundImage1 en este punto tiene el valor de "android".
  int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(backgroundImage1, "drawable", getPackageName());
  //Obtiene id de imagen cargada en ImageView2
  //backgroundImage1 en este punto tiene el valor de "robotito".
  int resourceId2 = getResources().getIdentifier(backgroundImage2, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

al obtener los id obtenemos el Drawable a partir del id:

```
  //convierte el id de imagen cargada en ImageView1 a Drawable.
  Drawable myDrawable1 = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
  //convierte el id de imagen cargada en ImageView2 a Drawable.
  Drawable myDrawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId2);
```

ahora podemos intercambiar las imagenes:

```
   //Asigna imagen de ImageView2 a ImageView1.
   imageView1.setImageDrawable(myDrawable2);

   //Asigna imagen de ImageView1 a ImageView2.
   imageView2.setImageDrawable(myDrawable1);
```

para obtener el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo el id del recurso en el sistema podemos cargar dinamicamente otra imagen,

```
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     //Carga imagen de ImageView2 a ImageView1
     imageView1.setImageDrawable(myDrawable2);
}
});
imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     //Carga imagen de ImageView1 a ImageView2
     imageView2.setImageDrawable(myDrawable1);
}
});
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Una respuesta muy elaborada :)

Comment: Que bien espero te sea de utilidad, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que programar un evento que desencadene el cambio, comúnmente se utiliza on clicklistener es decir, cada que hagas click al imageView, lo puedes cambiar de la siguiente manera:

```
puesto_1_foto_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    puesto_1_foto_1.setImageResource("Aqui va la el fondo dos");
}
});
```

Y haces algo similar para el imageview dos:

```
puesto_2_foto_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    puesto_2_foto_2.setImageResource("Aqui va la el fondo uno"); 
}
});
```

Comment: Si. Eso lo sé. Lo que estoy preguntando es si existe alguna forma de conseguir el nombre del background de cada TextView. Por ejemplo, si el primero tiene un background llamado a través de un drawable llamado "fondo1", ¿existe alguna forma de acceder a ese nombre?